# sed: replace a string in a text only if enclosed within quotes

Tags: bash, sed

I need to use sed to replace a sequence of characters in a text only if that particular sequence of characters belongs to a string contained within quotes.

e.g. the following text:

> This is a YouTube video referenced by the 'movies.YouTube_id' column.

should be transformed like this:

> This is a YouTube video referenced by the 'movies.you_tube_id' column.

i.e. replacing the substring "YouTube" with "you_tube" only if such substring is part of a string enclosed within single quotes ('), no matter of the leading and/or trailing characters enclosed within quotes.

Obviously

```
sed -r "s/YouTube/you_tube/g"
```

doesn't work because it replaces "YouTube" with "you_tube" everywhere regardless of the quotes. Which regular expression can I use to accomplish the task?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E "s/('[^']*)YouTube([^']*')/\1you_tube\2/g" file
```

Output:

```
This is a YouTube video referenced by the 'movies.you_tube_id' column.
```

Comment: This solution works nicely if the string to be replaced occurs only once in each quoted string - if it occurs more than once, then only the last occurrence in each quoted string is replaced.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk` solution for this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\047"} {
for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(/YouTube/, "you_tube", $i)} 1' file

This is a YouTube video referenced by the 'movies.you_tube_id' column.
```

Sinec we are using single quote as field delimiter, each even numbered field will give us quoted string surrounded by single quote.

Comment: Good solution (although it's not sed!). Unlike the accepted sed solution, this can do multiple replacements within each quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is not fixed (not already the same), then using *look around* advanced regexes and [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -pe "s/(?<=')(:?\w+\.)?YouTube(?=_id')/you_tube/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you on same:

```
awk '{sub(/\047movies.YouTube_id\047/,"\047movies.you_tube_id\047")} 1'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
This is a YouTube video referenced by the 'movies.you_tube_id' column.
```